# How can I change an array of documents to an array of values in MongoDB shell?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-shell

So, basically, I have this array of IDs:

```
> arrayDeptID
[
    {
        "departamento_id" : 0
    },
    {
        "departamento_id" : 2
    },
    {
        "departamento_id" : 5
    },
    {
        "departamento_id" : 6
    }
]
```

And I want to transform it to an array that contains only the **values** on the document field **departamento_id**, something like this:

```
[0, 2, 5, 6]
```

Is there any way to do it in MongoDB shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScipt [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
arrayDeptID.map(function(el) { return el.departamento_id })
```

Then MongoDB shell is a JavaScript REPL. So just about all ECMAScript built-in functions exist. It is built on V8, so whatever is in there is generally in here too.